# LINQ - FirstOrDefault() then Select()

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query that fires an exception when the `FirstOrDefault()` returns null. Ideally I would like to avoid the null check. Is there a way to do this? I wish to return `0` if there are no `CPOffsets` that satisfy the `FirstOrDefault()` call.

```
double offset = OrderedOffsets.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OffsetDateTime > cpTime).CPOffset;
```

The only way I can see to achieve this is the following:

```
CPOffset cpOffset = OrderedOffsets.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OffsetDateTime > cpTime);
double offset = cpOffset != null ? cpOffset.CPOffset : 0;
```

Is there another more succinct way? Using `Select()` after the `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't compile but I thought might be appropriate here?

Comment: This is really about as succinct as you are going to get... most of the time "good enough" is good enough :-)

Comment: I agree. If you want it _more_ succinct you'll probably have to roll your own method or extension method. (which isn't necessarily a bad thing) EDIT: Nothing wrong with `double offset = DetermineOffset(OrderedOffsets, cpTime);` or `double offset = OrderedOffsets.DetermineOffset(cpTime)` or `double offset = OrderedOffsets.DetermineOffset(o => o.OffsetDateTime > cpTime);` if you want a bit more control over the predicate.

Comment: Check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791514/streamlined-way-to-do-c-sharp-run-time-type-identification-that-avoids-a-null-ch/14791613#14791613

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think this should work, I'm not near by VS to check it out...

```
OrderedOffsets.Where(o => o.OffsetDateTime > cpTime).Select(x => x.CPOffset).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Servy - would that be true if all the OffsetDateTime's are < cpTime?

Comment: @Servy , suppose `First` would be enough. How much better would it be  than using `FirstOrDefault`? 9 chars?

Comment: Slow, i wrote a own solution for this which is not iterating through the complete collection ( thats what he does with where ).

Comment: @felix-k - don't quite follow you there; I don't think this solution will iterate through the complete collection. The `Where` is an iterator and will only be called as often as needed. The `FirstOrDefault` will stop after the first item it finds.

Comment: @jdpilgrim You're right, at this time i didn't know this. But still its somehow nicer to have it in one single method call because its easier to read.

Answer (score 14):

`DefaultIfEmpty` can be used to ensure that the collection always has at least one element.

```
double offset = OrderedOffsets.Where(o => o.OffsetDateTime > cpTime)
    .Select(o => o.CPOffset)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .First();
```

Comment: Is this different or better than just calling `FirstOrDefault()` after the `Select()` like in the accepted answer?

Comment: @JohnB The main advantage is being able to provide the default value rather than it needing to be the default value of that type.

Answer (score 6):

I think a good pattern could be :

```
double offset = (OrderedOffsets.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OffsetDateTime > cpTime) ?? someDefaultObject).CPOffset;
```

with `someDefaultObject` an object holding default values... With this pattern, you can change easily you default values through your code !

If OrderedOffsets can be a struct you could also just put your default value there ! :)

Comment: OK, this would work, but, why do you think this would be better than NSGaga's answer. It doesn't require a temp obejct `someDefaultObject` and more readable(of course subjective)

Comment: yeah but i don't really like that we keep all the values > cpTime after the `Where` i prefer a method that return after it find the first element, what if the list is megahuge, do we really want to project all the CPOffset passing in a new form ? I think it's not worth it to save a line… I'd rather go for the two line initially in the question…

Comment: I think you should read more on Linq and lazy evaluation. NSGaga's answer will return as soon as it finds the first match. It would iterate all the list if it doesn't find a match which is also true  for your answer.

Comment: PS: `Where` and `Select` doesn't keep all the list in memory, they just read the items one by one. This is what IEnumerable<T> exists for.

Comment: i guess OrderedOffsets.Where(o => o.OffsetDateTime > cpTime) return a iEnumerable and has to evaluate OffsetDateTime for each element, that's only what I was saying. Does OffsetDateTime requires a complex calculation ? We can't say by design ! Lazy evaluation doesn't magically knows the value… On a 'megahuge' collection, the memory and execution load can be significant, that was what i was saying. Trying to do that to save a line is not worth it i think.

Comment: Ps : i would agree for where(...).first() but not the Select after it. Oh and... Yeah deciding to not define default object is subjective. I agree ! ;) really depends on the rest of the code ! Probably not worth it if it's used only on this line !

Comment: @Romain The `Where` will fetch `OffsetDateTime` the exact same number of times in your query as both mine and NSGaga's, it will get it for every element until it finds a match, or all of them if there is no match.  The `Select` that fetches `CPOffset` will be applied to *at most* one item in both mine and Gaga's answers, due to the lazy evaluation and potentially incomplete iteration of the `Select`.

Comment: @Servy , indeed incomplete iteration of the `Select` does it. How can we then explain that it takes 3 times more time in some cases (see the  
ideone.com/p6EvsN ) ?

Comment: @Romain It basically comes down to the fact that all of the operations are executing so incredibly quickly that the simple overhead of creating the state machine for `Select` is of noticable time.  Just modify the code such that the item with `P=2` is added *after* the 10,000 items with `P=99` instead of before.  Then you'll see it doesn't take 2x as long, it takes essentially the exact same amount of time.  Adding the `Select` adds a very small *constant* amount of time.  That amount is only noticeable when the real work is tiny in comparison, which is generally not the case.

Comment: here is some noticeable changes when the property accessed has a slow return mechanism : 
http://ideone.com/s6bkhS
As you proposed i did two tests, one with the pass value before and one with the pass value after. 
It still seems that my solution runs way faster when the condition is met early. Are you sure it's a constant amount of time added by the `Select` ?

Comment: more and more bench, it turns out for me that it is not constant, that it can be significant if the list is big and that it depends on the complexity of the getter of the property. Globally my solution runs usually (has to be double checked) between 2 and 10 times faster if the match is in the beginning of the list and runs approx. the same when it's at the end… I guess that settles it ! Any serious benchmark would be welcomed ! :)

Comment: http://ideone.com/yCftDU on this one, we gain almost half a second on a 10 elements IEnumerable ! Although a property which would take 20 ms to return is not so usual ;)

Comment: `Globally my solution runs usually between 2 and 10 times faster if the match is in the beginning of the list and runs approx. the same when it's at the end… I guess that settles it !`  That's exactly why I say that it adds a constant amount.  It takes an extra few hundred nanoseconds to add the select.  It doesn't matter if there is one item, or ten thousand, or zero, it always adds the same amount of time.  If the sum of everything else in the program is also only a few hundred nanoseconds then it's a 50% slowdown, if the rest of the program is 4 seconds it's a .01% slowdown.

Comment: @Romain So the lesson here is that if you have a few hundred nanoseconds to spare, feel free to call the select.  If ever nanosecond counts, you almost certainly shouldn't be using LINQ at all (and possibly not even C# at all).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26667/discussion-between-romain-and-servy)